# How to get Views Criteria Filter arguments inside Views API hook?

Tags: 7, views

My question is related to:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70551/how-to-sort-view-by-taxonomy-multiple-value-field-with-a-range-of-only-selected

I have an idea, but I didn't manage to find a way to get arguments passed to Views Filter Criteria.

I would like to get them inside [hook_views_pre_render](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7)

Could someone give me any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it.

In $view->filter property is an array of views filter handler objects. In selected object inside $hander->value array are arguments passed to this filter.